# C# EF - DBContext the best practice for updating objects in memory

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm creating an online text editor, where the user connects with the application using WebSocket.

When connected, an object called UserControl is created and maintained with a copy of the entity in memory until the user disconnects.

As the original code is too big and complex to understand, here's a minimalist example:

```
public class UserControl
{
    public int Id => Entity.Id;
    public int LastUpdateId => Entity.LastUpdate;

    private readonly User Entity;
    private readonly DatabaseConnection Database;

    public UserControl(DatabaseConnection database, User entity)
    {
        Entity = entity;
        Database = database;
    }

    public async void Update()
    {
        var context = Database.GetContext();

        User user = await context.Users.FirstAsync(a => a.Id == Id);
        user.LastUpdate++;

        if (context.SaveChanges() > 0)
            Entity.LastUpdate = user.LastUpdate;

        context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

As you can see, any change that needs updating in the database a new DBContext is created, then I look for the entity again to make the change and finally I update the entity that was in memory.

This process is causing confusion when the complexity increases.

I thought about the possibility of simplifying the update process by keeping the entity's DBContext open:

```
public class UserControl
{
    public int Id => Entity.Id;
    public int LastUpdateId => Entity.LastUpdate;

    private readonly User Entity;
    private readonly DatabaseContext Context;

    public UserControl(DatabaseContext context, User entity)
    {
        Entity = entity;
        Context = context;
    }

    public async void Update()
    {
        Entity.LastUpdate++;
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

However, I looked a lot about good practices for using the DBContext and they always say that the lifetime needs to be very short.

Does anyone have any suggestions for me to improve the structure of my code?

> I'm aware of the async/lock issues from the example code, the idea is
> just to represent as simply as possible how I'm dealing with the
> entity update issue in memory.

Comment: If there is no concurrent access to this entity (for example each connection always works with separate User instance) then in theory you might leave DbContext open. Otherwise you need to requery entity everytime anyway, because what if something else changed LastUpdate while you were working with it?

Comment: The only one that makes changes to the User Entity is the UserControl. Wouldn't thousands of open DBContext be a problem?

Comment: There should not be thousands of connections if you mean that. EF will grab connection from the pool when necessary and return back when done (for example when SaveChanges is called). It does not keep connection open.